# How to create folder in $USER $HOME using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible trying to become `$USER` then create `.ssh` folder inside `$HOME` directory and I'm getting `Permission denied`:

```
---
- hosts: amazon
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/env python3"
    account: 'jenkins'
    home: "{{out.stdout}}"

  tasks:
    - name: Create .SSH directory
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: "{{account}}"
      shell: "echo $HOME"
      register: out
    - file:
        path: "{{home}}/.ssh"
        state: directory
```

My output is:

```
MacBook-Pro-60:playbooks stefanov$ ansible-playbook variable.yml -v
Using /Users/stefanov/.ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [amazon] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Create .SSH directory] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [slave] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo $HOME", "delta": "0:00:00.001438", "end": "2017-08-21 10:23:34.882835", "rc": 0, "start": "2017-08-21 10:23:34.881397", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "/home/jenkins", "stdout_lines": ["/home/jenkins"]}

TASK [file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [slave]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "There was an issue creating /home/jenkins/.ssh as requested: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/home/jenkins/.ssh'", "path": "/home/jenkins/.ssh", "state": "absent"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/stefanov/playbooks/variable.retry

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
slave                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I'm guessing `- name` and `- file` are dicts and considered different tasks.
And what was executed in `- name` is no longer valid in `- file`?
Because I switched to Jenkins user in `- name` and in `- file` I'm likely with the account I do SSH.

Then how can I concatenate both tasks in one?
What is the right way to do this?

Another thing how can I do sudo with `file` module? I can't see such option:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html

Or should I just do shell: `mkdir -pv $HOME/.ssh` instead of using `file` module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Then how can I concatenate both tasks in one?

You cannot do it, but you can just add `become` to the second task, which will make it run with the same permissions as the first one:

```
- file:
    path: "{{home}}/.ssh"
    state: directory
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "{{account}}"
```

> Another thing how can i do sudo with file module can't see such option

Because `become` (and other) is not a parameter of a module, but a general declaration for any task (and play).

> I'm guessing -name and -file are dicts and considered different tasks.

The first task is `shell`, not `name`. You can add `name` to any task (just like `become`).

Comment: Thank you it was informative. Guess have to read some newbie guide.